# Print Screen to URL

Tags: webapp-rec

If you don't already know, you can use the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> button (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> for a single window) in Microsoft Windows to grab a screen shot and put it on your clipboard. Is there a website that can look at my clipboard, upload the image, and provide me a URL to the image that I can share with others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *exactly* what the original poster wanted and also what I wanted. I wanted to share this awesome tool for anyone else: http://snag.gy. You just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> after you print screen and it's there. There are also some editing tools (crop, drawing) if necessary.

Comment: Finally someone has found/made it! I did a quick test and it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 6):

*Copied/adapted from [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/150832/whats-the-shortest-way-to-post-a-cropped-screenshot-on-the-web/150836#150836) to [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/150832/whats-the-shortest-way-to-post-a-cropped-screenshot-on-the-web/) on SuperUser. Consider merging?*

1) **[TinyGrab](http://tinygrab.com/)**

You press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (configurable to what you want), then you click+drag to select an area with a crosshairs. It then uploads it directly to their service, and puts a short link to it on your clipboard (http://grab.by/shortID). It works quite well, is free, and can be used on OS X or Windows.
http://grab.by/4QPg

2) **[Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/)**

You click the Jing icon, click to select a window or use the crosshairs to select an entire region, then can take either a still screenshot or a screen video recording. It can then be automatically uploaded to Jing's servers, or you can set it to upload to your own FTP server.

Comment: Not a bad answer but I am asking for a website that can do this instead of an app. If we can't find one (or a way to make one) then this will ultimately be the solution.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. In that case, any of a variety of image upload services would work. It's going to be less convenient with solely a website, because it won't be able to take the screenshot, just do the uploading. After re-reading your question, I'd like to add that for security reasons, websites cannot just read your clipboard without your permission. There may be a solution using flash or silverlight, but not with regular JavaScript and HTML. With HTML5, there may be ways to drag-and-drop an image into the browser window to be uploaded. I'll keep my eyes out for a site like that.

Answer (score 3):

See also [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361324/pasting-an-image-from-clipboard-to-a-website). It appears there are at least a couple Java tools that will allow the pasting of an image form the clipboard.

Would be nice to know if there are an AJAX-y ones, too.

Comment: Looks like this might be the closest to what I want: http://lassebunk.dk/2009/08/04/clipboard-java-applet/ -- but I can't find a site that actually has it working. I'm going to dig into the code and see if I can figure it out

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons there is [no](http://www.pcmagic.org.uk/extra/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=66%3adisable-allow-this-webpage-to-access-your-clipboard&catid=69%3ainternet-help&Itemid=13) [easy](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Granting%20JavaScript%20access%20to%20the%20clipboard/discuss) way for JavaScript in a browser to access the clipboard. Browsers will show you warnings or may refuse the request completely. Probably that's why not many picture managment sites have such feature. A desktop software would be a much better suited tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Very handy!  [Imaer](http://imaer.net/) can upload a file, clipboard data, or screen selection to Imgur.  It does require a right-click > Upload Clipboard, it won't automatically do it, but still so handy.

Edit:  Also, depending on what version of Windows you are on, the Snipping program can come in handing for getting the right screenshot.  You can save or copy to the clipboard in Snipping, and then use Imaer to get a Imgur url.

Answer (score 1):

There is going to have to be some kind of desktop connect for this to happen.

Try [iClippy](http://iclippy.com/) , it is the closest you will get.

> **How does iClippy work?**
>
> iClippy works by capturing the visuals
> from screen, camera, or scanner to an
> online clipboard without having to
> save the pictures to the local
> computer first.  The images are
> immediately available for pasting into
> email, online document, blog, instant
> message, twitter, facebook, or any
> other number of resources.  The images
> are also searchable both from the web
> and from the local sidebar.  The
> images are automatically scaled down
> to the size that’s appropriate for
> online resources and as defined by the
> account type.
>
> **Can I access the images in my clipboard from the desktop?**
>
> Yes, iClippy comes with a native
> sidebar application which allows you
> instant access to your iClippy
> library.  The sidebar allows listing
> through pages of images, narrowing
> down the set through search, pinning
> the image to not be replaced, copying
> the image into the local clipboard for
> further use with local or online
> resource, deleting an image, following
> the link which is attached to the
> image, and more..
>
> **Provide me a URL to the image that I can share with others?**
> To find a link to an image, proceed to http://my.iclippy.com, find the image you’d like to share, and send its URL.

The limitation here at least for me to vet it, is that it is for Windows only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dropbox, then it's easy. Just copy and save the image and put it into the Dropbox public folder. Then right click -> Dropbox -> Copy Public URL and voila!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you attach an image right here, it creates a URL (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxxxx.png) that you can send to others and persists over time. If the image you save is your screenshot saved to a file (in MSPaint even) you can easily share your image with others.